# Memcached - Test with telnet - strange result

Tags: php, json, session, memcached

I'm storing my PHP session with memcached using `$memcached->set('sessions/'.$sessionId, json_encode($_SESSION), 1000);` which works just fine within PHP. But if I open a connection with telnet and type `get sessions/123123` it results in strange signs like `Â$Áª"P«UMÎ­uë].ùç` where I expect to have some JSON string.

Any idea on that would be much appreciated.

Comment: the cache record may be deflated/gzipped.

Comment: Or could be serialized

Comment: @Orangepill thats what I also had in mind. I use default settings. How do I change the compression on the console?